# Unity monetization errors

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

[image]

I have Unity 2022.3.14f1. I am learning Unity Monetization. I got an error like this. I don't have JDK. I worked to download the JDK, but I didn't download the JDK.

How can I fix the this errors? Also I don't have gradle script.